# Can I auto-fill an answer on a form edit URL?

Tags: google-forms

I periodically send out emails to our team to check in on from entries that have a specific field set to "No". And after they complete a certain task then need to change that entry to "Yes". The easiest way I've found to do this is to have them go to the form edit URL and just change the last question themselves.

However, to make it easier, I would like to auto-fill that change that final questions to a "Yes" instead of a "No" through the Edit URL.

Is this possible?

If this is not possible, any suggestions for a more user-friendly way to edit a response? If I could generate a link that runs a script with a unique identifier that would work as well, or even a link that causes the specific spreadsheet cell to change would work too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured that out rather quickly.

If you take your form URL:`docs.google.com/a/mydomain/forma/d/uniqueFormString/viewform?edit2=uniqueEditString`

Get your elements number and value by getting a pre-filled URL. ie. `&entry.688631299=Yes` and insert it right after the `viewform?` and append a `&` after your elements number and value.

The URL should look like: `docs.google.com/a/mydomain/forma/d/uniqueFormString/viewform?&entry.688631299=Yes&edit2=uniqueEditString`

Go to that URL and the specific question will be changed. Now if I could just figure out how to auto-submit the form to make it even easier.

Comment: Are you still trying to figured out how to auto-submit a form response?

Comment: I am not. I figure out how to POST to the form